# eglGetError() reporting success for errors

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, error-handling, android-ndk

I am using EGL/Android/NDK, and trying to check errors, but eglGetError() is returning EGL_SUCCESS even when I intentionally cause an error.

Under windows, this code produces GL_INVALID_OPERATION, but when using egl through the android NDK, I get  EGL_SUCCESS..

```
glClear(GL_TEXTURE0);
Print("gl error: ", eglGetError());
exit(0);
```

Anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eglGetError() is for EGL functions (they have prefix egl).
To check errors for OpenGL functions (with gl prefix) use glGetError() function.